# JS_newObject API crashes, probably Garbage Collector issue

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, thread-safety, spidermonkey

So I am trying to run a code on release 64 platform. I am using spidemonkey 1.8.5 .  the following code crashes at line JS_NewObject(). My guess is it is related to GC triggered inside the API. I have tried other APIs that do the same thing, I've also tried BeginRequest and EndRequest. none of them helped.

The same code works perfectly when linked to Spidermonkey 1.7.

```
 int InitJS()
{   
m_jsRunTime = JS_NewRuntime(JS_RUN_TIME_MEM);
if ( NULL == m_jsRunTime )
{           
    return 0;
}

m_jsContext = JS_NewContext(m_jsRunTime, JS_CONTEXT_MEM);
if ( NULL == m_jsContext )
{
    return 0;
}    

//JS_BeginRequest(m_jsConetxt);//just to test no help
//ASSERT(m_jsContext);ASSERT(&JS_GLOBAL_CLASS);//these are fine. no null pointer
//JSObject *myObject = JS_NewObject(m_jsContext, &JS_GLOBAL_CLASS, NULL, NULL);//just to test->this also carshes
//m_jsGlobalObject = JS_NewObjectwithGivenProto(m_jsContext, &JS_GLOBAL_CLASS, NULL, NULL);//just to test ->identifeir not found
//m_jsGlobalObject = JS_ConstructObject(m_jsContext, &JS_GLOBAL_CLASS, NULL, NULL);//just to test->crashes


m_jsGlobalObject = JS_NewObject(m_jsContext, &JS_GLOBAL_CLASS, NULL, NULL);//the original line
if ( NULL == m_jsGlobalObject)
{
     return 0;
}

if ( !JS_InitStandardClasses(m_jsContext, m_jsGlobalObject) )
{
return 0;
}
JS_EndRequest(m_jsContext);//just to test
return 1;
```

}

the core dump file points to this line in jsgcinlines.h

```
inline JSObject *

js_NewGCObject(JSContext *cx, js::gc::FinalizeKind kind)

{

    JS_ASSERT(kind >= js::gc::FINALIZE_OBJECT0 && kind  
<=js::gc::FINALIZE_OBJECT_LAST);

    JSObject *obj = NewFinalizableGCThing<JSObject>(cx, kind);

    if (obj)

        obj->capacity = js::gc::GetGCKindSlots(kind);

    return obj;

}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow for spidermonkey is not active. Your best bet is the irc channel #jsapi on moz irc channels. Here is mibbit, an html5 client: https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsapi  Another place you can try is http://ask.mozilla.org/